# The directions in which the directional derivative of a real valued function on an $n$-dimensional space is 0 make up an $(n-1)$ dimensional subspace

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This is a question from Loomis and Sternberg's *Advanced Calculus*: Let $f: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $V$ is an $n$-dimensional space and let $f$ be differentiable at $a \in V$. Show that the directions, $\xi$, such that the $D_\xi f(a) = 0$, make up an $(n-1)$ dimensional subspace.

I feel like this should be a simple question, but I'm having a hard time showing this. I don't even know where to start really. I know that we have $$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{f(a+t\xi)-f(a)}{|t|} = 0$$

But it's not clearly to me how I can work with this to arrive at a solution.

Comment: try to define the map $G:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: v \mapsto D_vf(a)$ and see what the properties of this map are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative at an input point is a linear operator from changes "around" that input (which live in an n-dimensional space, in this case) to changes "around" its corresponding output (which live in a 1-dimensional space, in this case). A linear operator from n-dimensional space to 1-dimensional space is either constantly zero, or has an (n - 1)-dimensional space of zeros (this is a special case of the "rank-nullity theorem").